# Virtual Router disconnects some devices and won't allow them to reconnect

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

I'm using Virtual Router Manager v1.0, had to go through some hoops to get it to work. The problem I have is after some minutes/hours, devices that are connected to the virtual router are booted out of the network, and can't reconnect, while other devices can't even connect in the first place. Apparently, my iPhone is the only device that gets permanent connectivity for some reason. Yesterday my tablet had perfect connectivity, but after one or two hours, I lost connection and couldn't reconnect no matter what I did, while my iPhone had perfect connection.

The only "fix" for this is to restart my pc and run the Virtual Router Manager again, but this is obviously annoying since I would have to restart my PC like 10 times a day.

Obviously the PC didn't lose internet connection since I could use the internet on it and my iPhone with no problem. It isn't a password problem since it didn't change.